# Url Rewrite to another server for specific file (reverse proxy) does not work in Umbraco 8 site

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, umbraco, arr

I need to serve a script file from a third-party server as if it is coming from my own server. Should be a simple reverse proxy thing with url rewrite.

**Prerequisites:**
IIS has Url Rewrite 2.0 and ARR 3.0 installed.

**What works:**
when I set up an empty localhost website in IIS and add a simple rewrite rule like

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
          <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="localJs/proxiedScriptFile.js" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="https://thirdpartyserver.de/js/script.js" />
          </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can navigate to `localhost/localJs/proxiedScriptFile.js` and I get correctly served `https://thirdpartyserver.de/js/script.js` instead. So ARR and Rewrite is working.

**What doesn't work:**

When I add the same rewrite rule to the web.config of my existing Umbraco 8 website (on the same IIS), I get a HTTP 404.4 error, as if ARR does not work.

**What I tried:**

- If in Umbraco 8, I change the rewrite to point to a local dummy file of
  the same type, it works - the local dummy file is served. But the file off the third-party server is not.
- Adding the rewrite path or url to
  Umbraco.Core.ReservedUrls or Umbraco.Core.ReservedPaths does not
  change the problem.

Any idea what I am facing here?

Kind regards!
Mikael

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using an OWIN middleware as a proxy, rather than using UrlRerwrite/ARR. This worked right away.

If someone comes up with a pure UrlRewrite/ARR solution, I am still interested. Here what works for me:

I found this [ReverseProxyMiddleware](https://github.com/RoadTrain/ReverseProxyMiddleware) for .Net Framework. Using this, my OwinStartup contains the following code:

```
    public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // this must come before the base implementation so proxy kicks in before Umbraco

        app.UseProxy(
            new List<ProxyRule> {

                // script proxy
                new ProxyRule {
                    Matcher = uri => 
                        uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localJs/proxiedScriptFile.js")
                    ,
                    Modifier = (req, user) => {
                        req.RequestUri = new Uri("https://thirdpartyserver.de/js/script.js");
                    },
                    RequiresAuthentication = false
                }
            },
            r =>
            {
            }
        );

        base.Configuration(app);

    }
```

Works like a charm. I post it here in case somebody else faces the same challenge.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, please mark your answer as the correct answer.